# how can i write text next to previous lines on a txt with python?

Tags: python

i have this on a txt name it
-------ocr_results.txt

```
0361.bmp:0345
0363.bmp:0027
0365.bmp:0349
0367.bmp:0351
0369.bmp:0353
0371.bmp:0355
0373.bmp:0357
0375.bmp:0010
0377.bmp:0361
0379.bmp:0363
0381.bmp:0008
```

------and have results like

ocr_results_modified.txt

```
0361.jpg:0345
0363.jpg:0027
0365.jpg:0349_dislinearity
0367.jpg:0351
0369.jpg:0353
0371.jpg:0355
0373.jpg:0357
0375.jpg:0010
0377.jpg:0361_dislinearity
0379.jpg:0363
0381.jpg:0008
```

----------how can i have results like ?

```
0361.jpg:0345
0363.jpg:0027_dislinearity
0365.jpg:0349
0367.jpg:0351
0369.jpg:0353
0371.jpg:0355
0373.jpg:0357
0375.jpg:0010_dislinearity
0377.jpg:0361
0379.jpg:0363
0381.jpg:0008
```

how can i write next to previous lines on a txt with python ?

---------------i use this code

renamer .py

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# create Tkinter window to choose input file
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# prompt user to choose input file using file dialog window
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])

# read contents of input file and modify lines
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    lines = [line.replace("bmp", "jpg") for line in f.readlines()]

# create a dictionary to store the last four characters of each line
last_four_dict = {}

# create a new file to write the modified lines
output_file_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + "_modified.txt"
with open(output_file_path, "w") as f:
    # process each line of input file
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        # extract last four characters of line
        last_four = line[-5:-1]
        new_line = line.rstrip()

        # check dislinearity of last four digits
        if last_four.isdigit() and i > 0 and i < len(lines) - 1:
            prev_last_four = lines[i - 1][-5:-1] 
            next_last_four = lines[i + 1][-5:-1] 
            if prev_last_four.isdigit() and next_last_four.isdigit():
                diff_prev = abs(int(last_four) - int(prev_last_four))
                diff_next = abs(int(last_four) - int(next_last_four))
                if not diff_prev <= 2 and diff_next <= 2 and int(last_four) != int(next_last_four):
                    new_line += "_dislinearity"

        # write the modified line to the output file
        f.write(new_line + "\n")
```

This code reads the contents of a user-specified input file (with a .txt extension) and modifies each line by replacing the substring "bmp" with "jpg". It then creates a new output file with the same name as the input file, but with "_modified" appended to the filename, and writes the modified lines to this file.

The code also checks for linearity of the last four digits of each line, and appends "_dislinearity" to the line if the following conditions are met:

```
the last four digits are digits (i.e., not characters)
the line is not the first or last line of the file
the last four digits of the previous and next lines are digits
the difference between the last four digits of the current and previous lines is greater than 2
the difference between the last four digits of the current and next lines is less than or equal to 2
the last four digits of the current line are not equal to the last four digits of the next line.
```

The program stores the last four characters of each line in a dictionary named last_four_dict.

Note that the program uses the os and tkinter libraries to interact with the operating system and display a file dialog window to prompt the user to select an input file.

Comment: FYI try to distill your question down into a short sample, and you'll get better responses. Most people will not want to decipher your verbose code to get to the meat of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below does what you want, I think

```py
import os


file_path = 'ocr_results.txt'
output_file_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + '_modified.txt'

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.replace("bmp", "jpg") for line in f.readlines()]

with open(output_file_path, "w") as f:
    for i in range(1, len(lines) - 1):
        new_line = lines[i - 1].rstrip()
        prv = lines[i - 1][-5:-1]
        cur = lines[i][-5:-1]
        nxt = lines[i + 1][-5:-1]
        if prv.isdigit() and cur.isdigit() and nxt.isdigit():
            diff_prv = abs(int(cur) - int(prv))
            diff_nxt = abs(int(cur) - int(nxt))
            if not diff_prv <= 2 and diff_nxt <= 2 and int(cur) != int(nxt):
                # print(i, prv, cur, nxt, diff_prv, diff_nxt)
                new_line += '_dislinearity'
            f.write(new_line + '\n')
    f.write(lines[-2])
    f.write(lines[-1])
```